# How to install 64-bit version of Realm in android studio?

Tags: java, android, realm

Prior to Google announcement about 64-bit support to all android apps, i already trying analyze my apps if it's contain some 32-bit native library that should be updated. There's two library that's 32-bit, it is a EPSON library and Realm library, for the EPSON i will take it out because it is currently not used, but for the Realm database, i really need the 64-bit version. Can anyone suggest me or point out how to install Realm dependency that support 64-bit version in android studio? i'm using java

**EDIT FOR SOLUTION :**

 As EpicPandaForce comment below, there's one library in my project that only support 32-bit version, thereby the other library will use the 32bit version. When i removed the 32-bit only library the other library automatically use the 64 bit version.

Comment: Which version of Realm are you using ?

Comment: I'm using realm 2.3.1

Comment: Can you confirm that there is no ```librealm-jni.so``` file in ```lib/arm64-v8a``` or ```lib/x86_64``` folder in apk ,You can use ```Apk Analyzer``` present in Android Studio for that

Comment: I can confirm that there's no lib/arm64-v8a and lib/x86_64 folder in the apk

Comment: You should be having ```lib/arm64-v8a``` folder because Realm add support for ARM 64 in Version 0.79

Comment: How can i get that folder? Can i get that folder by simply installing the dependency? Or there's some config need to be done?

Comment: Try Increasing the version of Realm you are using, Latest is 5.12.0...I am using 3.7.2 and it exports both 32 bit and 64 bit libs to apk

Comment: I just update it, and it doesn't produce the 64 bit folder. Do i need to build signed apk? Or just build apk is enough?

Comment: I think debug build is enough

Comment: Is it because other native library that support only 32 bit?

Comment: I don't think so ,Realm is an independent library

Comment: If you are using at least one 32-bit library, then it will also use 32-bit library for Realm. It's in the FAQ in the docs. This is because of Android internal quirkery.